# Trying to build oe image with framebuffer

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto, framebuffer, openembedded

conf/local.conf

```
MACHINE ??= "genericx86-64"
PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= "package_ipk"
SDKMACHINE ?= "x86_64"
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES ?= "debug-tweaks"
USER_CLASSES ?= "buildstats image-mklibs image-prelink"
#TEST_IMAGE = "1"
#OE_TERMINAL = "auto"
PATCHRESOLVE = "noop"
BB_DISKMON_DIRS ??= "\
    STOPTASKS,${TMPDIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,${DL_DIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,${SSTATE_DIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,/tmp,100M,100K \
    ABORT,${TMPDIR},100M,1K \
    ABORT,${DL_DIR},100M,1K \
    ABORT,${SSTATE_DIR},100M,1K \
    ABORT,/tmp,10M,1K"

PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-qemu-native = " sdl"
PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-nativesdk-qemu = " sdl"

CONF_VERSION = "1"

IMAGE_FEATURES += "splash package-management ssh-server-openssh allow-empty-password hwcodecs empty-root-password "
MACHINE_FEATURES_append = " acpi alsa keyboard pci pcbios screen touchscreen wifi serial rtc"
DISTRO_FEATURES_remove = " wayland x11"
DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " systemd opengl directfb kms splash keyboard pci wifi "

PACKAGECONFIG_GL_pn-qtbase = "gl gles2 eglfs linuxfb libinput directfb udev kms"
PACKAGECONFIG_X11_pn-qtbase = ""
PACKAGECONFIG_FB_pn-qtbase = "linuxfb kms directfb"

IMAGE_INSTALL += " python3-pyyaml python3-pyusb python3-pyudev python3-pyserial python3-cffi python3-evdev python3-pip"
IMAGE_INSTALL += " kernel-modules packagegroup-base-extended packagegroup-base-wifi"
IMAGE_INSTALL += " libdrm mesa-megadriver mesa libinput libudev fbida dietsplash ttf-fonts"

DISTRO="poky"

DISTRO_FEATURES_BACKFILL_CONSIDERED += "sysvinit"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_init_manager = "systemd"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_initscripts = "systemd-compat-units"
```

conf/bblayers.conf

```
LCONF_VERSION = "7"

BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BBFILES ?= ""

BBLAYERS ?= " \
  /home/eri/oe-core/meta-clang \
  /home/eri/oe-core/meta \
  /home/eri/oe-core/meta-rtlwifi \
  /home/eri/oe-core/meta-yocto/meta-yocto-bsp \
  /home/eri/oe-core/meta-yocto/meta-poky \
  /home/eri/oe-core/meta-qt5 \
  /home/eri/oe-core/meta-intel \
  /home/eri/oe-core/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  /home/eri/oe-core/meta-openembedded/meta-python \
  /home/eri/oe-core/meta-pyside2 \
  "
```

Run:

```
bitbake core-image-full-cmdline
```

I want `/dev/dri/card0` and `/dev/fb0` on qemu, intel and amd internal video. But I have no kernel video drivers in rootfs...

Comment: Try copying a test image using, cp /home/root/test.jpg /dev/fb0 , to see if the framebuffer is working.

Comment: @abunickabhi there is no  /dev/fb0